# this keyword and inheritance - Java

Tags: java, inheritance, this

Ok, so this has been messing with me. (double entendre?)

*ignoring variable types since that's not the issue*

Lets say you have a parent class, for example a book class, with variable ISBN. The constructor sets ISBN using `this.ISBN = bla`.

Now there's a child class. It has a constructor that calls the parent one inside it. First, how is the contructor formed? Like this? :

```
public kidsBook(ISBN, kidVariable) {
   super(ISBN);
   this.kidVariable = kidVariable;
}
```

Is that the right way to do it? If so that brings up the second question: the this.ISBN from the parent class, when the constructor from the parent is called in the child constructor does the this keyword refer to the child's version of ISBN?

It's really been confusing me and I bet the way I wrote it shows that confusion in spades.

Edit: Fixed code mistakes not related to the question.

Comment: What you have there is not a constructor.

Comment: How is it not a constructor? @kirk

Comment: constructors cannot have return type.

Comment: Constructors do not have return types.  And calls to the base constructor are not named, it's simply `super(ISBN)`.  What you have there is a normal method.

Comment: Whoops, always forget the first part (return type). And the second was written that way out of ignorance (super.book). :P but thanks @kirk & @stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. The answers to your questions are yes and yes.

Here's what the complete code would look like with right syntax

```
class Book {
    String ISBN;

    Book(String ISBN) {
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
    }
}

class KidsBook extends Book {
    String kidsVariable;
    KidsBook(String ISBN, String kidsVariable) {
        super(ISBN);
        this.kidsVariable = kidsVariable;
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU @stack! I was worried the this would refer to the class it was originally in.

Comment: And the same goes for methods that you overwrite on the child class!

Comment: The OP asks, when in the context of the super-class constructor, what `this` refers to.  The correct answer is that it refers to the super-class, not the sub-class (child-class), and thus the super-class version of the field `ISBN` and not the sub-class version.

Comment: I just realized that the question I'm asking is kinda pointless. Since the the this.ISBN will still be a part of the object of type kidBook anyway. :P Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: Meaning that the variable is part of the object anyway, so it doesn't matter which it refers to, right? @kirk@stack@miquel

Comment: @Portaljacker, you are correct.  However, it is legal for the child class to *also* declare an `ISBN` field.  In that scenario, the question would be significant.

Comment: @kirk, but wouldn't it just replace the one from the parent? And then you wouldn't set it in the super, you'd set it alongside the kidVariable.

Comment: @Portaljacker, yes, but in relation to your original question, `this.ISBN` in the *super* -class would refer to the super-class' version of `ISBN`, not the child-class version.

Comment: @kirk Ok, but could just writing `ISBN = bla` in the parent constructor set the new ISBN made in the child? Using this.variable for everything would save us from this I guess. Though you can still use super.ISBN right? Super only calls the parent, not grand-parent, right?

Comment: @Kirk ISBN is part of super class but with the contract of inheritance, a reference to extending class has props from both base and child but `this` refers to the child class. If you set a break point in eclipse in the base class's constructor, when called from child class, it would say `this` is an instance of child class.

Comment: @stack, does that mean you can refer to the child and parent's ISBN to have 2 ISBN without making a new one in the child?

Comment: @Portaljacker No there is only one ISBN when you create a child's instance.

Comment: @stack, so no using super.ISBN unless you create a new ISBN in the child?

Comment: @Stack, you are right that the OP intended that there be one field.  However, as I mentioned, it is legal for the child-class to have a field with the exact same name.  While the debugger shows the runtime type information of the object, this is completely distinct from the compile-time information, and at compile-time, the reference *within* the super-class constructor would be a reference to the super-class' version of `ISBN`.  I admit this is tangental to the original question, but it was not clear to me at the time whether he might have been duplicating the field as I described.

Comment: @kirk, nope, simple school assignment. I wouldn't be making a new version in the child, so it kinda makes my whole question pointless then right? As long as I don't make a new version of course.

Comment: @Portal, yep, but a fun discussion. :)

Comment: @kirk, indeed. I was trying to learn it from the fragments of what I was paying attention to in class. I usually love programming classes but the class is at night this semester so it's hard to be that excited. :P

Answer (score 0):

The constructor would be:

```
public KidsBook(ISBN isbn, Foo kidVariable) {
   super(isbn);
   this.kidVariable = kidVariable;
}
```

Now, you are passing in the `isbn` parameter from `KidsBook`'s constructor to the constructor of its superclass.  The constructor of that superclass is:

```
public Book(ISBN isbn) {
   this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

In the end the `isbn` instance variable (equivalently, `this.isbn`) is equal to the original `isbn` passed into the KidsBook constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here another example that hopefully clarifies some mechanics of java inheritance.

```
public class Book
{
  protected String isbn;

  public Book(String isbn)
  {
    this.isbn = isbn;
  }

  public Book()
  {
    // isbn not set
  }
}

class DoubleIsbnBook extends Book
{
  private String isbn;

  public DoubleIsbnBook(String isbn)
  {
    super(); // could be commented out, since super class' constructor is implicitly called anyway
    super.isbn = isbn; // since Book's isbn is protected, it's visible at this point
    this.isbn = isbn.toUpperCase(); // here we set DoubleIsbnBook's isbn
  }

  public DoubleIsbnBook(String isbn1, String isbn2) {
    super(isbn1); // if Book's isbn was private this would be the only way to set Book's isbn
    this.isbn = isbn2;
  }
}
```